# Overwrite value in memory by taking in user input

Tags: c, stack-smash

This is related to a stack smash attack.

Basically, I am trying to smash the stack by giving a program a particular input. The program takes in a user input like this, using `getchar`:

```
for (i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++) buf[i] = c;
```

I want to overwrite memory to become `0x000000a1`. Unfortunately, `0xa1` is not an ascii character, so I cannot just input something like `¡` (inverted exclamation) because that ends up giving `0x0000a1c2` in memory. How can I overwrite the value to be just `0x000000a1` without changing how the user input is processed in the program?

Comment: Something like `int main() { putchar(0xa1); putchar('\n'); }`?

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks for the response. to further clarify, I mean I can only provide an input to the program. the program will ask "enter a string" when it is run, and then it reads the input using `getchar`. But I can't find the character corresponding to `0xa1`...so I can't change the program programatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bash to inject arbitrary characters:

```
echo -e '\xA1' | /path/to/program
```

You can add additional input, put the echo in a loop, etc.

```
echo -e 'Something\xA1\xA1\xA1' | /path/to/program
```

Answer (score 1):

Your system's information is not provided, but usually the standard input is just a byte stream. It means that you can send arbitrary byte stream, not just valid characters.

For example, if your victim program is `./a.out`, you can create a program to emit a payload

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    putchar(0xa1);
    putchar('\n'); /* to have the victim finish reading input */
    return 0;
}
```

and compile to, for example, `./b.out` and execute using a pipe

```
$ ./b.out | ./a.out
```

(`$` is your terminal's prompt)

Comment: I did not mention this as well, but I can only use a text file at most for the input. Thanks for helping anyway!

Comment: @umopapisdn `0xa1` stands for `｡` in a text file encoded in Shift-JIS. You should be able to use that!

Comment: As a matter of fact, how did you find this character? When I did a search, I could only find the inverted exclamation mark, which is in fact `0xc2a1`

Comment: I entered `A1 0A` to a binary editor (TSXBIN) and opened the file with a text editor (SAKURA Editor).

Comment: Handy trick...thanks for the help! I'll keep it in mind next time